# How to create infinite pipe of strings in bash

Tags: bash, xargs

I have about 10 links in file links.txt. I download them through

```
cat links.txt | xargs -i --max-procs=4 bash -c "wget {}"
```

I whould like do it repeatedly like

```
while :
do
   cat links.txt | xargs -i --max-procs=4 bash -c "wget {}"
done
```

Before the next iteration of while loop it waits all subprocesses to be finished. But I would like to continue downloading (take url from beginning of the file) when there is an available thread. How to do that? May be I can make infinite pipe of strings?

Comment: I would try to loop only the `cat`: `while :; do cat links.txt; done | xargs -i --max-procs=4 bash -c "wget {}"`

Answer (score 3):

If your `yes` accepts a string argument:

```
yes links.txt | xargs cat | xargs -n1 --max-procs=4 wget
```

No point in running one `cat` perl `links.txt` or one `bash` per link (unless you want the lines of `links.txt` to be interpreted as shell code like `http://$host$path` or `http://evil;rm -rf /`).

If the file is small enough, you can also do:

```
yes -- "$(cat links.txt)" | xargs -n1 -P4 wget
```